# Why does It send a mail twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I have a program that sends automatic mails to people who are on my database. I am taking the people to data table with this code:

```
private DataTable verileri_cek() 
{
    consql.Open();
    string kayit = "SELECT * from kisiler where 
        DATEPART(DAY,dogumtarihi)=DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE()) and 
        DATEPART(MONTH,dogumtarihi)=DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE())";
    SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(kayit, consql);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(komut);
    DataTable dt =new DataTable(); 
    da.Fill(dt);
    consql.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Then I want to send mail to people who are on the data table. I have to recieve 2 emails for my two different e-mail. But It send two times for the one. Why?
This is my part of code to send mail:

```
private void Saat10()
{
    DataTable dt=verileri_cek();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[i]["durum"].ToString() == "Akademik")
            {
                mesaj.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mesaj.Subject = "Doğum Günü";
                mesaj.Body = "Sayın Akademik Personelimiz" + dt.Rows[i]["isim"].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i]["soyisim"].ToString() + " " + "Doğum Gününüz Kutlu Olsun";

             }
             else
             {

                 mesaj.IsBodyHtml = true;
                 mesaj.Subject = "Doğum Günü";
                 mesaj.Body = "Sayın İdari Personelimiz" + " " + dt.Rows[i]["isim"].ToString() + "  " + dt.Rows[i]["soyisim"].ToString() + " " + "Doğum Gününüz Kutlu Olsun";

             }
             mesaj.To.Add(dt.Rows[i]["mail"].ToString());
             client.Send(mesaj);

         }
     }

 }
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Put the  MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage(); inside for loop, otherwise it doesn't get reinitialized.

Comment: You're sending the mail in a loop.  Why is it surprising that you're sending more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new `MailMessage` object for each user:

```
 private void Saat10()
 {
    DataTable dt=verileri_cek();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
           mesaj = new MailMessage();

           // all other code
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: @SteveGates no problem glad I could help you out!

Comment: @SteveGates bear in mind to assign this as the answer so other people who have the same problem direclty see the solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend printing each time what you've got before you actually send the mails. Of course you can also debug. In your example you need to create the message inside the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
     MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage();
     if (dt.Rows[i]["durum"].ToString() == "Akademik")
     {
           mesaj.IsBodyHtml = true;
           mesaj.Subject = "Doğum Günü";
           mesaj.Body = "Sayın Akademik Personelimiz" + dt.Rows[i]["isim"].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i]["soyisim"].ToString() + " " + "Doğum Gününüz Kutlu Olsun";


     }
     else
     {
           mesaj.IsBodyHtml = true;
           mesaj.Subject = "Doğum Günü";
           mesaj.Body = "Sayın İdari Personelimiz" + " " + dt.Rows[i]["isim"].ToString() + "  " + dt.Rows[i]["soyisim"].ToString() + " " + "Doğum Gününüz Kutlu Olsun";

     }
     mesaj.To.Add(dt.Rows[i]["mail"].ToString());
     client.Send(mesaj);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you are saying correctly, and you want a new message for each row in the returned table, then you need to move:

```
MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage();
```

..into your For..Loop instead of just after you've checked if there are rows.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    MailMessage mesaj = new MailMessage();

    //< rest of your code here>

    mesaj.To.Add(dt.Rows[i]["mail"].ToString());
    client.Send(mesaj);
}
```